# TightVNC Viewer Remote Desktop

Tags: desktop, viewer

I am using TightVNC Viewer to Remote Desktop my RHEL virtual machine from Windows. But it  just shows me almost half of my RHEL desktop with lots of black space on both sides of the window. I want to be able to view my full RHEL desktop . Ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you specify the geometry of your vncserver session on the RHEL host?  E.g.,

```
$ vncserver -geometry 1520x1060
```

or whatever your screen size is, in pixels.

Trick w/ TightVNC is to make your geometry about 20 pixels less than your actual screen (to account for Windows window decoration without adding scrollbars).  And/or use

```
<ctrl>-<shift>-<alt>-f
```

(yes, all four keys at the same time) to use full-screen mode on your Windows box.  Latter is most useful with multiple monitors, since it tends to hide everything else.